# If a bowl contains $x$ red candies and $y$ yellow ones, what is the likelihood that $2n$ randomly drawn candies are $n$ yellow and $n$ red?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If a bowl contains $x$ red candies and $y$ yellow ones, what is the likelihood that a randomly drawn handful of $2n$ candies will contain an equal number of reads and yellows?

I would also assume that all $n$ are pulled at the exact same time in one handful.

(This is an edit for a general solution). The original has x = 30, y = 20, and 2n = 8, which is the solution given below

Comment: Why would you change the question after receiving an answer? When I answered you had shown your working which you now removed and there was no ask for a general solution then. I feel your edit makes the answer less relevant and also makes it look like you have no thoughts of your own on this. My request is to avoid this in future.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you are picking at once or one by one is not relevant. What is relevant though that you are picking without replacement.

So for example, while the probability of first candy being red is $\frac{3}{5}$, it is $\frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{29}{49}$ for the first two being red.

Now, it is easier to express the probability of picking $4$ red and $4$ yellow candies as,

$ \displaystyle {30 \choose 4} {20 \choose 4} / {50 \choose 8} = \frac{252909}{1022626}$